# "When specifying a local instance, always use (local)" -- why?

Tags: sql-server

On the subject of SQL Server connection strings, Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx):

> When specifying a local instance, always use (local).

The implication is that using `localhost` is a bad idea.  But why?  Or am I reading too much into the wording?

Comment: I can't think if any reason why `(local)` would be preferred over `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `.`... unless it is a named instance. In fact I would almost always prefer to use the machine name or FQDN, even when local, so that regardless of where I'm running the code (or have copied it) it will still connect to the right server. Of course you could go the other way on this, if your code always runs local but you're porting it to different environments. But I see no reason to prefer `(local)` over any of the others, and am actually confused that the doc implies that there is...

Comment: H'mmm - I've always used . (dot) or the servername / instance name. Never had an unexplained problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from memory and without reference so my recall may not be accurate.

IIRC for 2005+ "(local)", "localhost" and "." are equivalent and will use the Shared Memory protocol. Prior to 2005, "(local)" and "." would use Shared Memory whereas localhost would not necessarily do so by default. Use of machine name or FQDN *could* result in a DNS lookup so is not recommended for a local machine connection.

Lastly, the "(local)" term (including brackets) is a special keyword, rather than a reference to the local machine.

Comment: That all sounds about right.